# Admin on rest : Error data format

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I use admin-on-rest with aor-simple-graphql-client to work with an apollo server. But I have an error when i try to edit or create with admin-on-rest.

This picture shows the format of the data.

[image: This picture show the format of the data]

Admin on rest doesn't know $name but $name is a part of the data.
The repo I use : https://github.com/JeresB/cuistot-aor

Answer (score 0):

Your `Workshop` does require a `name` ([schema.js](https://github.com/JeresB/cuistot-aor/blob/master/src/server/data/schema.js)):

```
createWorkshop(
    id: ID, name: String!, price: Int!, duration: Int!, min_gourmet: Int!,
    max_gourmet: Int!, description: String!, pictures: JSON, kitchen_id: ID,
    cook_id: ID, workshop_date: Date!
): Workshop
```

Comment: I know that why I give to admin on rest every variable he need but aor-simple-graphql-client store all variables into "data" and admin-on-rest doesn't understand that and say "variable name must be provided" even if name is store into "data"

Comment: We can't see and the picture but i wrote Test for the name, we can name equal "Test" in the data variable

Comment: Sorry I missed the part where you said you use aor-simple-graphql-client.. Indeed, this very naive first version will send the entity as string (JSON.stringify) under the key `data` to your backend as explained in the [readme](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-simple-graphql-client#create-a-new-resource)

Comment: Please note that this client was a POC and will be deprecated soon in favor of [aor-graphql](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-graphql/). This repository provides a basis to implement a graphql client for admin-on-rest. We currently have implemented a graphcool version and we will work on sample simple graphql implementation soon.